# Copying files from a series of directories based off a list in a text file

Tags: bash, shell, rsync, directory-structure, file-manipulation

I am attempting to use either `rsync` or `cp` in a `for` loop to copy files matching a list of 200 of names stored on new lines in a `.txt` file that match filenames with the `.pdbqt` extension that are in a series of subdirectories with one parent folder. The `.txt` file looks as follows:

```
file01
file02
file08
file75
file45
...
```

I have attempted to use rsync with the following command:

```
rsync -a /home/ubuntu/Project/files/pdbqt/*/*.pdbqt \
--files-from=/home/ubuntu/Project/working/output.txt \
/home/ubuntu/Project/files/top/
```

When I run the rsync command I receive:

```
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at options.c(2346) [client=3.1.2]
```

I have written a bash script as follows in an attempt to get that to work:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in "$(cat /home/ubuntu/Project/working/output.txt | tr '\n' '')"; do
    cp /home/ubuntu/Project/files/pdbqt/*/"$i".pdbqt /home/ubuntu/Project/files/top/;
done
```

I understand `cat` isn't a great command to use but I could not figure out an alternate solution to it, as I am still new to using bash. Running that I get the following error:

```
tr: when not truncating set1, string2 must be non-empty
cp: cannot stat '/home/ubuntu/Project/files/pdbqt/*/.pdbqt': No such file or directory
```

I assume that the `cp` error is thrown as a result of the tr error but I am not sure how else to get rid of the `\n` that is read from the new line separated list.

The expected results are that from the subdirectories in `/pdbqt/` with the 12000 `.pdbqt` files the 200 files from the output.txt list would be copied from those subdirectories into the `/top/` directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for` loops are good when your data is already in shell variables.  When reading in data from a file, `while ... read` loops work better.  In your case, try:

```
while IFS= read -r file; do  cp -i -- /home/ubuntu/Project/files/pdbqt/*/"$file".pdbqt  /home/ubuntu/Project/files/top/; done </home/ubuntu/Project/working/output.txt
```

or, if you find the multiline version more readable:

```
while IFS= read -r file
do
    cp -i -- /home/ubuntu/Project/files/pdbqt/*/"$file".pdbqt /home/ubuntu/Project/files/top/
done </home/ubuntu/Project/working/output.txt
```

#### How it works

- `while IFS= read -r file; do`

  This starts a `while` loop reading one line at a time.  `IFS=` tells bash not to truncate white space from the line and `-r` tells `read` not to mangle backslashes.  The line is stored in the shell variable called `file`.
- `cp -i -- /home/ubuntu/Project/files/pdbqt/*/"$file".pdbqt /home/ubuntu/Project/files/top/`

  This copies the file.  `-i` tells `cp` to ask before overwriting an existing file.
- `done </home/ubuntu/Project/working/output.txt`

  This marks the end of the `while` loop and tells the shell to get the input for the loop from `/home/ubuntu/Project/working/output.txt`

Comment: Thank you for the in depth explanation. I had seen some while examples but didn't think that was going to work in my case.

Comment: You're welcome.  The issue with the `for` loop approach is that it is difficult to control the various expansions (principally _word splitting_ and _pathname expansion_) that the shell applies to it.  The `while...read` approach avoids all that.

Answer (score 0):

Do dirs in `Project/files/pdbqt/*` or files `*.pdbqt` have dashes (`-`) in the name?

The error is showing the line in rsync source code [`options.c`](https://github.com/mrjoshuak/rsync-3.1.2/blob/6eeb4d1184460f16cf66f2aa2ea648f81d3aacff/options.c) 
`"Your options have been rejected by the server.\n"`

which makes me think that it's interpreting inodes (files/dirs) in your glob as rsync options.

```
for i in $( < /home/ubuntu/Project/working/output.txt LC_CTYPE=C tr '\n' ' ' )
do
  cp /home/ubuntu/Project/files/pdbqt/*/"${i}.pdbqt" /home/ubuntu/Project/files/top/
done
```

I think your cat tr is missing a space

`cat /home/ubuntu/Project/working/output.txt | tr '\n' ' '`

[John1024](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56335068/3335343)'s use of `while` and `read` are better than mine.

Comment: OOOOOH I do have dashes in the names. That explains it. Didn't even think of them. Won't be using those again.

Answer (score 0):

Your are thinking correctly to think `rsync`. `rsync` provides the option `--files-from="yourfile"` that will `rsync` all the files in your `textfile` (relative to the base directory you specify next) to the destination (either `host:/dest/path` or locally with `/dest/path` alone)

You will want to specify the `--no-R` to tell `rsync` not to use relative filenames since `--files-from=` takes the base path as the next argument. For example, to transfer all files in your text file to some remote host where the location of the files specified are in the current directory, you could use:

```
rsync -uai --no-R --files-from="textfile" ./ host:/dest/path
```

Where the command essentially specifies you read the names to transfer from `textfile` where the files will be found under `./` (the current directory) and you will transfer the files to `host:/dest/path` on the `host` you specify. You can see [man 1 rsync](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rsync.1.html) for full details.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful comment, it made how rsync works a fair bit clearer. When attempting to do it this way however, it only searched in the current directory and not into the subdirectories from the current tree?

Comment: No, it searches from the base directory for whatever the file names in your text file say the files are. Let's say your text file has `"project/1/study.txt\nproject/2/data.txt\n..."`, then if your base directory is `./` it looks for `./project/1/study.txt`, or if you base directory was `/home/you/`, it would look for `/home/you/project/1/study.txt`. (that's the reason `--no-R` is needed, so `rsync` doesn't attempt to append relative names to your base directory)